# Facebook Graph: unable to get group feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed, facebook-group

I'm trying to get the group feed via Facebook Graph API.

According to the documentation

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/group/feed

I'm trying to costruct the appropiate url and here it is

[https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/154205721275156/feed?access_token=[TOKEN]](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/154205721275156/feed?access_token=%5BTOKEN%5D)

And each and every time I'm getting the next result

> {    "error": {
>
> ```
>   "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
>   "type": "OAuthException",
>   "code": 1,
>   "fbtrace_id": "B7/12QU7BW/"
> ```
>
> } }

[TOKEN] is valid, it applies to the member of the group.

At the same time other requests for the same group, such as "/events" or "/members", return correct answers.

What is wrong with the "/feed" request?

Comment: is the group secret or closed? you cannot get access to all groups anymore, only to those you are an admin of.

Comment: Group privacy is "OPEN". Do you mean that I can't access even opened group's feed if I'm not an admin of this group?

Comment: maybe, yes. in general, you should not need to get the feed of groups you don´t own anyway.